# The value for session.save_path (/tmp) is not writable for the web server. Make sure that PHP can actually save session variables

Tags: php, linux, session, centos

I am trying to install a script on my CentOS VPS, and I managed to resolve most of the errors except of one:

```
    The value for session.save_path (/tmp) is not writable for the web server. Make sure that PHP can actually save session variables.
```

I have used the following commands, but it did not help at all:

```
    chmod 777 /tmp
    chmod 777 /tmp/*
    service httpd restart
```

the error still persists.

I have searched all over the internet, and here on stackoverflow, but the only answer I can find is to chmod the /tmp folder, what I have done.

Any advise on this one?

Thanks

Comment: what does `ls -l -a` print?

Answer (score 0):

How about this `chmod 1777 /tmp` If not, then you must be sure that during script run, tmp is actually 777, maybe script mess some permissions during run. If not, then i don't know) Maybe something with ACL access?

EDIT:

i found this https://groups.drupal.org/node/61893, looks similarly to your problem, problem was in ACL permissions, so consider looking ACL permissions of /tmp.

Comment: Why 1777, maybe try 0777 instead?

Comment: just because it is default for /tmp, and it doesn't preventing from writing. Anyway i think problem with ACL

Answer (score 0):

Disable selinux can solve your problem. Edit `/etc/selinux/config` and set `SELINUX=disabled`, then reboot.